# VkApi, Python. messages.send. Как отправить сообщение, содержащую информацию из файла .txt?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, текст

Имеется следующий код:

```
f = open('name.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
f_read = f.read()

session.method('messages.send', {
                'user_id': 1234567890,
                'message': f.read(),
                'random_id': 0
            })
```

Проблема в жалобе, которая гласит, что в поле message неправильно задан параметр или оно пустое:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stas\Desktop\python\strbot\1.py", line 13, in <module>
    session.method('messages.send', {
  File "C:\Users\Stas\Desktop\python\strbot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 668, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid
```

При этом код не воспринимает в том поле ни f.read(), ни переменную f_read, в которой находится функция чтения. Через print() вся информация из файла выводится корректно, проблема лишь в заполнении 'message'.

UPD: ответ на задачу: необходимо поставить виртуальный курсор в файле в начало текста с помощью f.seek(0), после чего передавать данные с помощью переменной f_read

Comment: Возможно текст имеет слишком большую длину.

Comment: Нет. Сейчас ради интереса создавал новый файл с несколькими символами. Абсолютно то же самое. Да и в ВК в сообщениях лимит символов большой. Даже если перегнуть палку, он просто лишние символы не отправит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open()` создает потоковый объект, а значит каждый байт данных вы можете получить из него только один раз. Что значит это для вас? Да то что после использования `f.read()` при записи переменной вы оставляете `f` пустым. Об этом же вам и пишет `Traceback`. Раз вы считали все в переменную то и передавайте ее в `session.method()`. https://tproger.ru/articles/files-in-python/ - для уверенности, что понимаете, как работать с файлами правильно. Удачи!

Comment: (возможно вам это понадобится. Чтобы прочитать открытый файл снова, используйте предварительно на нем `f.seek(0)` - это вернет каретку чтения в начало файла)

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы предлагаете поместить переменную 'f' (или 'f_read', содержащую функцию чтения) в 'message'? Если да, то как я и описал выше в вопросе, я это пробовал, выдает ту же ошибку.  
Я начал изучать VkApi недавно, поэтому пока возникают трудности. Очень хотелось бы увидеть в тексте, как правильно передавать информацию в 'messages'. Спасибо!

Comment: В f_read не содержится никакая функция. В ней содержится содержимое всего файла в виде строки.

Comment: В любом случае, содержимое из f_read не воспринимается в `messages`

Comment: Сохраните словарь который вы передаете в функцию в переменную, принтаните ее, и дайте выхлоп сюда

Comment: сервис printscrn не работает, поэтому: https://screenshare.ru/867pPiUZ. 
Это динамический документ. Сюда будет сохраняться некоторая информация после парсинга, после чего весь текст из файла нужно отправить в сообщения человеку, а после этот файл уничтожается. Сейчас проблема только с отправкой текста.

Comment: Благодарю, действительно, требовалось поставить виртуальный курсор в начало файла с помощью f.seek(0), после чего с помощью переменной f_read я смог передать. Спасибо за ценную информацию